# From picture in cell to footer

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Given a workbook like this one:

[image]

I need to add the logo from cell A2 - worksheet A, in the footer of worksheets B,C.

Here's the code I've found and modified a little bit but it is not working.

```
Sub Logo()

Dim printWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim logoShape As Shape
Dim tempImageFile As String

Set printWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set logoShape = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A").Shapes("myLogo")

tempImageFile = Environ("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "image.jpg"
Save_Object_As_Picture logoShape, tempImageFile

With printWorksheet.PageSetup
.RightHeaderPicture.FileName = tempImageFile
.RightHeader = "&G"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solutions (http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?538529-Export-an-Image-from-Excel-Sheet-to-Hard-Drive), that I have adopted to this task.
The key is, that a chart object can be exported as a picture, so the original shape is copied into a chart. 
The chart is created, used, and deleted. 
The ShapeExportAsPicture has two arguments: the shape, that is to be exported as picture and the full path where to store it.

```
Sub Logo()
    Dim printWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim logoShape As Shape
    Dim tempImageFile As String

    Set printWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set logoShape = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A").Shapes("myLogo")
    logoShape.Visible = True
    tempImageFile = Environ("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "image.jpg"
    Call ShapeExportAsPicture(logoShape, tempImageFile)

    With printWorksheet.PageSetup
        .RightFooterPicture.Filename = tempImageFile
        .RightFooter = "&G"
    End With
    logoShape.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub ShapeExportAsPicture(pShape As Shape, sPathImageLocation As String)
    Dim sTempChart As String
    Dim shTempSheet As Worksheet
    Set shTempSheet = pShape.Parent
    Charts.Add 'Add a temporary chart
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=shTempSheet.Name
    Selection.Border.LineStyle = 0
    sTempChart = Selection.Name & " " & Split(ActiveChart.Name, " ")(2)
    With shTempSheet
        'Change the dimensions of the chart to the size of the original shape
        With .Shapes(sTempChart)
            .Width = pShape.Width
            .Height = pShape.Height
        End With
        pShape.Copy  'Copy the shape
        With ActiveChart 'Paste the shape into the chart
            .ChartArea.Select
            .Paste
        End With
        'export the chart
        .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export Filename:=sPathImageLocation, FilterName:="jpg"
        .Shapes(sTempChart).Delete 'Delete the chart.
      End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Viktor. The logo duplicates in worksheet A but doesn't appear in the footer (or header) of any worksheet (besides it doesn't delete itself). The error I get is runtime error 70 permission denied

Comment: Sorry. I put into the header. Just replace the RightHeaderPicture with RightFooterPicture and  RightHeader with LeftHeader. Also you can hide the shape from the sheet using logoShape.Visible = False

Comment: Yes I've already changed that (RightFooterPicture and RightFooter) but the error keeps popping up: "permission denied". It seems that the deletion part doesn't go through

Comment: Sorry hearing it. I guess the problem could be that you have no right to the directory set by your line: tempImageFile = Environ("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "image.jpg". Try to go by step by step (F8) and check which line cause the problem. Also check the path (tempImageFile). If you have no access to the path, than change it. I hope it will solve the problem.